# Dynamically create uibarbutton dosent work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

uibarbutton not responding.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

When ever user tap the button then no any actions fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need also use following code for the UIbarbutton.

```
UIBarButtonItem *cameraView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera
                               target:self action:@selector(showCam)];
```

Or Also you can use following code.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                        target:self
                                                                              action:@selector(showCam)];
```

it may also helping to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE"
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(methodName:)] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a delegate that will handle the button callbacks (the 'target' parameter, typically, 'self', and the name of the method to be invoked, which is the 'action' parameter).

```
backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                 initWithTitle:@"Back"
                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                     target:self
                     action:@selector(backButtonAction:)];
```

Include the action method, 'backButtonAction' in the class specified as the target.  So, if using 'self', include the method in the same class that's adding the button, as follows

```
- (void) backButtonAction:(id) sender
{
    NSLog (@"backButtonAction: Sender %p", sender);

    ....
}
```